# php-mime-mail-parser php library return error

Tags: php, parsing

I have download the library by using composer & add this code in php file:

```
require_once __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php';
$parser = new PhpMimeMailParser\Parser();
```

But it return the error in log file:
PHP Fatal error: **Uncaught Error: Class 'PhpMimeMailParser\Parser' not found**

mailparse extension already installed on my server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the right syntax is

`require_once __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php'; $parser = new PhpMimeMailParser();`

Look at the [Reference](https://mail-mime-parser.org/) here.

Comment: We are using different mail parser library: https://github.com/php-mime-mail-parser/php-mime-mail-parser, You are giving different library reference.

Answer (score 0):

After some digging i found that it has to be loaded with:

```php
$parser = new eXorus\PhpMimeMailParser\Parser();
```

you might also need to install mailparse extension and enable it in php.ini

you can find updated usage in:

vendor/php-mime-mail-parser/php-mime-mail-parser/README.md